# Second level of ordering

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering, tabs

Would it be possible to introduce a second level of ordering and/or filtering in Stack Overflow? Let me give you a couple of examples to illustrate what I mean:

- If you are in the unanswered tab, it would be really useful to then be able to sort by newest
- If you are in newest, it would be great to filter out questions with accepted answers

Comment: funny. First option mentioned in the answer is available at P.SE: `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest` but at SO, I couldn't find it

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3a0), or something else?

Comment: @gnat: That is also available in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest). But it gives us questions with **no upvoted answers**

Comment: [I think this is the first filter](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0)

Comment: @hims056 thanks! I couldn't find it because I was looking from the wrong tab `http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered`

Comment: [This is newest unaccepted question list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3a0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This filters can be achieved with [search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search)

> 1.If you are in the unanswered tab, it would be really useful to then be able to sort by newest

- Write on search box `answers:0` and click on newest tab. It will give you [the desired list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers:0).

> 2.If you are in newest, it would be great to filter out questions with accepted answers

- Write on search box `hasaccepted:0` and click on newest tab. It will give you [the desired list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted:0).

Note that unanswered question means: question with **no upvoted answers**